# 'mussh' does not ask for password

Tags: linux, ubuntu-18.04, fedora-30

**update:**  if mussh is dead/non-fixable, please suggest what replaces them. I tested pssh (not working returning undocummented status), dsh (not in public repos)

I'd like to connect to several machines to verify if I can log in. There is some cyberarch stuff going on which limits my options, but the idea which should work is to read password to env variable, and then use `sshpass` and `mussh`. But I found out, that even if I use `mussh` alone to login to my localhost, it does not ask for password at all. Any ideas why or what can I do with it?

```
ssh mmucha@localhost 'echo is alive'
mmucha@localhost's password: <me entering password here>
is alive
```

and now via `mussh`

```
mussh -A -b -m 5 -h mmucha@localhost -c 'echo is alive'
mmucha@localhost: mmucha@localhost: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).
```

options in order are "no ssh-agent" "no mingling of hosts output" "parallelism" "host specification" "command to be executed."

with debug enabled(I'm omitting beginning):

```
localhost: debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
localhost: debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
localhost: debug3: preferred gssapi-with-mic,publickey
localhost: debug3: authmethod_lookup gssapi-with-mic
localhost: debug3: remaining preferred: publickey
localhost: debug3: authmethod_is_enabled gssapi-with-mic
localhost: debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
localhost: debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
localhost: No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: KCM:)
localhost: 
localhost: debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
localhost: No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: KCM:)
localhost: 
localhost: debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
localhost: debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
localhost: debug3: remaining preferred: 
localhost: debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
localhost: debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
localhost: debug1: Offering public key: /home/mmucha/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:e7mLi9WbP5ghs8J5nYWK317OihY9g6jl+iUnFTN+0GQ explicit agent
localhost: debug3: send packet: type 50
localhost: debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
localhost: debug3: receive packet: type 51
localhost: debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
localhost: debug1: Offering public key: keyForAlfonz19@github RSA SHA256:+BmoR+Sw2kgh7Fygoi99to8B/RrrF/QKL2GO4+xP3SI agent
localhost: debug3: send packet: type 50
localhost: debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
localhost: debug3: receive packet: type 51
localhost: debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
localhost: debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
localhost: debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
localhost: mmucha@localhost: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).
```

when I check the same debug for ssh, the line with `Authentications that can continue` gets smaller, while there's only password left, and then I'm asked. While for `mussh` this line still shows the same list of methods, which is kinda weird.

Comment: "please suggest any other tool, which works" – (1) Questions seeking product recommendations are off-topic. (2) `ssh` + GNU `parallel`?

Comment: well GNU mussh should work. GNU pssh should work. I'm not looking for recommendation. Primarily I'd like to know how to make them work and if I'm not doing anything wrong. If they're dead and was replaced by newer, modern alternative (there are also questions regarding that already), I'm just saying, that I'd like to know about such replacement.